# Dynamic value for max length in a regex

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

i need to validate differents input value lengths.

Inputs value can have a max length of 6 / 15 / 25 characters. Now i was asking to my self if it's a good practice use only one dynamic regex to validate differents max lengths, instead of copy paste the same regex.

During my research i found that i've to use the the `const regex = new RegExp()`

the problem is that i tried

```js
const lengthValidation = () => {
  const maxLength = 4;
  const inputValue = 'ciao';
  const regex = new RegExp(`/^.{6,${maxLength}}$/`);
  const isValid = regex.test(inputValue);
  return console.log('regexTest', isValid);
};

lengthValidation();
```

but it's invalid.

where is my mistake ?

Comment: The expression is interpreted as a string, so you could simply concatenate it before using the `+` operator.

Comment: it was the template literals, thanks. Could you answer please :) you fixed it.

Comment: The right value should be greater than the left value `{6,4} -> Wrong`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, you could simply use the `+` operator as in

```js
const lengthValidation = () => {
  const maxLength = 4;
  const inputValue = 'ciao';

  let expression = '^.{' + maxLength + ',6}$';
  const regex = new RegExp(expression);

  const isValid = regex.test(inputValue);
  return console.log('regexTest', isValid);
};
lengthValidation();
```

Be aware though that e.g. `.{6,4}` will lead to an error as the engine requires the quantifiers to be in the correct order. You might build in a check before otherwise the expression will fail.
Additionally, for a simple length check, a regular expression might be a bit of an overkill.

Comment: your previous example 

```export const lengthValidation = (inputValue: string, minLength: number, maxLength: number) => {
  const regex = new RegExp(`^.{${minLength},${maxLength}}$`);
  const isValid = regex.test(inputValue);
  return console.log('regexTest', isValid);
}; ``` was perfect to fix my case. 

I used ' ciao ' just a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the slashes from the regex string. Slashes are only needed to create a Regex when you are using the `var regex = /expr/;` notation.

Also, you need to use a lower bound of e.g. 1 character, not 6:

```js
const lengthValidation = () => {
  const maxLength = 4;
  const inputValue = 'ciao';
  const regex = new RegExp(`^.{1,${maxLength}}$`);
  const isValid = regex.test(inputValue);
  console.log(regex);
  console.log('regexTest', isValid);
};

lengthValidation();
```